# Rails save copy of original when model is edited

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple scaffold:

```
rails g scaffold Order name:string notes:text
```

I would like for the user to be able to edit their order but keep copies of the past versions for reference. I considered adding a separate "Revision" model that would hold the text instead, but I would also like the form to stay populated with the most recent information for easy editing.

sorry for not posting more code, I'm not sure what would be helpful

Comment: cant you just have the server create a new order instead of updating the older one in your controllers?

Comment: Have a look at [**paper_trail**](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail)

Comment: #PhilVarg I was thinking about it, but later on the order will also have attachments and other relations, I really want just the "notes" to be saved.

Comment: @Pavan, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the better idea is create two models: **Order and OrderHistory**

Order will have a relation 1 to much to OrderHistory.

In update action of your OrderController you have to create a OrderHistory with the previous data and with foreign key pointing to Order. Also you can use default rails fields like create_date for getting the last revised version and mantain a good history of them.

*Is a bad practise use Model Order for do that as I said.*

```
class OrderController < ApplicationController::Base
  before_action :set_order #implement this function


  def update 
    orderHistory = OrderHistory.create(@order.params) #this code can fail I don't remmember how exactly do that now
    respond_to do |format|  
      if @order.update(order_params)
         orderHistory.save
      else 
      #response in fail case
      end
    end 


  end
end
```

Comment: I was thinking something similar but I'm not sure how to implement it, would you mind giving me an example?

Comment: I put you an aproximation of what it could be

Comment: I'll try it in an hour or so, I'm still new at this so I might have some questions.  Yours looks like a correct answer to me.  Can you think of any reason [https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) would not work?

Comment: It probably works too, I never saw it. I think that if you need all features of paper_trail maybe could be a better way, but if you need simplicity I think that your own code could be a better way.

Comment: The idea is not use a sledgehammer to crack nuts